# Systems of second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

i'm following a course in Hamiltonian systems and regarding the part of linear systems I found this exercise from a book and need to solve it. My ideas are just after the test of the exercise.

Consider the system $(*)$ $Mq'' + V q = 0$, where M and V are n × n symmetric
matrices and $M$ is positive definite. From matrix theory there is
a nonsingular matrix $P$ such that $P^T MP = I$ and an orthogonal matrix
$R$ such that $R^T (P^T V P)R = Λ = diag(λ1, . . . , λn).$ Assume now that the above equation can be reduced to $p''+Λp = 0$.

a) Show that if V has one negative eigenvalue, then some solutions of
$(*)$ tend to infinity as $t→±∞$.

b) Consider the system $(**)$ $Mq'' + ∇U(q) = 0$, where $M$ is positive
definite and $U : R^n → R$ is smooth. Let $q_0$ be a critical point of $U$
such that the Hessian matrix of $U$ at $q_0$ has one negative eigenvalue (so $q_0$ is not a local minimum of $U$). Show that $q_0$ is an unstable critical
point for the system $(**)$

---

My idea for point a) is to use the undamped pendulum to visualize this: i know that in the phase plane when you have a negative eigenvalue if i am right solutions are from the origin to infinity .

Comment: @Dan 
that's right, can you please remember me the general solution form for this kind of differential equations ? $x(t)=e^(\lambda_i *t) x_o ?$

Comment: You can solve the system directly for the first part all solutions corresponding to positive eigenvalues oscillate while the negative eigenvalue yields exponentials